# objective-c invalid operands to binary expression double to double

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
-(double) pixelDistance:(float)lat1 Lng1:(float)lng1 Lat2:(float)lat2 Lng2:(float)lng2 Zoom:(double)zoom{
    double x1 = [self lngToX:lng1];
    double y1 = [self latToY:lat1];

    double x2 = [self lngToX:lng2];
    double y2 = [self latToY:lat2];
    return sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2)+ pow((y1-y2),2)) >> (21 - zoom);
}
```

how to fix "invalid operands to binary expression double to double"?
error at return line.

Comment: Probably because you can't use a bitwise right-shift operator `>>` with doubles they have to be integer values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right shift operator >> requires two integer arguments, not two double arguments.